# M2.4.5 Bulk update attributes not working

Tags: cron, magento2.4.5, bulk-products-update

In my Magento 2.4.5 open source store, bulk update attributes are not working. Cron is running, and it appears everything else is running fine. Emails are being sent out for example.

I have this code in app/etc/env.php:

```
    'cron_consumers_runner' => [
        'cron_run' => true,
        'max_messages' => 10000,
        'consumers' => [
        ]
    ],
```

and

```
    'queue' => [
        'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 0
    ]
];
```

We are not running rabbitmq as our hosting (Cloudways) only supports it on a premium support package.

Can anyone advise how to get this running again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In app/etc/env.php:

Change cron_consumers_runner to:

```
'cron_consumers_runner' => [
'cron_run' => true,
'max_messages' => 10000,
'consumers' => [
product_action_attribute.update,
product_action_attribute.website.update,
exportProcessor,
media.storage.catalog.image.resize,
matchCustomerSegmentProcessor,
codegeneratorProcessor,
sales.rule.update.coupon.usage,
sales.rule.quote.trigger.recollect,
product_alert,
staging.synchronize_entity_period,
negotiableQuotePriceUpdate,
sharedCatalogUpdatePrice,
sharedCatalogUpdateCategoryPermissions,
inventory.source.items.cleanup,
inventory.mass.update,
inventory.reservations.cleanup,
inventory.reservations.update,
inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus,
inventory.indexer.sourceItem,
inventory.indexer.stock,
media.content.synchronization,
media.gallery.renditions.update,
media.gallery.synchronization,
placeOrderProcessor,
purchaseorder.toorder,
purchaseorder.transactional.email,
purchaseorder.validation,
quoteItemCleaner,
inventoryQtyCounter,
async.operations.all
]
],
```

This worked for us.